# ArrayAccess in PHP -- assigning to offset by reference

Tags: php, arrays, reference, arrayaccess

First, a quote from the ole' manual on [`ArrayAccess::offsetSet()`](http://php.net/manual/en/arrayaccess.offsetset.php):

> This function is not called in assignments by reference and otherwise indirect changes to array dimensions overloaded with [ArrayAccess](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) (indirect in the sense they are made not by changing the dimension directly, but by changing a sub-dimension or sub-property or assigning the array dimension by reference to another variable). **Instead, [ArrayAccess::offsetGet()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/arrayaccess.offsetget.php) is called. The operation will only be successful if that method returns by reference, which is only possible since PHP 5.3.4**.

I'm a bit confused by this. It appears that this suggests that (*as of 5.3.4*) one can define `offsetGet()` to return by reference in an implementing class, thus handling assignments by reference.

So, now a test snippet:

<sub>(*Disregard the absence of validation and `isset()` checking*)</sub>

```
class Test implements ArrayAccess
{
    protected $data = array();

    public function &offsetGet($key)
    {
        return $this->data[$key];
    }

    public function offsetSet($key, $value)
    {
        $this->data[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function offsetExists($key) { /* ... */ }

    public function offsetUnset($key) { /* ... */ }

}

$test = new Test();

$test['foo'] = 'bar';
$test['foo'] = &$bar; // Fatal error: Cannot assign by reference to
                      // overloaded object in

var_dump($test, $bar);
```

Ok, so that doesn't work. Then what does this manual note refer to?

> **Reason**
>   I'd like to permit assignment by reference via the array operator to an object implementing `ArrayAccess`, as the example snippet shows. I've investigated this before, and I didn't think it was possible, but having come back to this due to uncertainty, I (*re-*)discovered this mention in the manual. Now I'm just confused.

---

**Update**: As I hit <kbd>Post Your Question</kbd>, I realized that this is likely just referring to assignment by reference **to another** variable, such as `$bar = &$test['foo'];`. If that's the case, then apologies; though knowing how, if it is at all possible, to assign by reference to the overloaded object would be great.

---

**Further elaboration**: What it all comes down to, is I would like to have the following method aliases:

```
isset($obj[$key]);       // $obj->has_data($key);

$value = $obj[$key];     // $obj->get_data($key);

$obj[$key] = $value;     // $obj->set_data($key, $value);

$obj[$key] = &$variable; // $obj->bind_data($key, $variable);

// also, flipping the operands is a syntactic alternative
$variable = &$obj[$key]; // $obj->bind_data($key, $variable);

unset($obj[$key]);       // $obj->remove_data($key);
```

As far as `has`, `get`, `set`, and `remove` go, they're no problem with the supported methods of `ArrayAccess`. The binding functionality is where I'm at a loss, and am beginning to accept that the limitations of ArrayAccess and PHP are simply prohibitive of this.

Comment: +1 this is a perfect example of a good question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does not work with `ArrayAccess`, you could add yourself a public function that allows you to set a reference to an offset (sure, this looks different to using array syntax, so it's not really a sufficient answer):

```
class Test implements ArrayAccess{

    protected $_data = array();

    public function &offsetGet($key){
        return $this->_data[$key];
    }

    ... 

    public function offsetSetReference($key, &$value)
    {
        $this->_data[$key] = &$value;
    }
}

$test = new Test();
$test['foo'] = $var = 'bar';
$test->offsetSetReference('bar', $var);    
$var = 'foo';    
echo $test['bar']; # foo    
$alias = &$test['bar'];    
$alias = 'hello :)';    
echo $var; # hello :)
```

Probably such a function was forgotten when `ArrayAccess` was first implemented.

**Edit:** Pass it as "a reference assignment":

```
class ArrayAccessReferenceAssignment
{
    private $reference;
    public function __construct(&$reference)
    {
        $this->reference = &$reference;
    }
    public function &getReference()
    {
        $reference = &$this->reference;
        return $reference;
    }
}


class Test implements ArrayAccess{
    ...
    public function offsetSet($key, $value){
        if ($value instanceof ArrayAccessReferenceAssignment)
        {
           $this->offsetSetReference($key, $value->getReference());
        }
        else
        {
           $this->_data[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
```

Which then works flawlessly because you implemented it. That's probably more nicely interfacing than the more explicit `offsetSetReference` variant above:

```
$test = new Test();
$test['foo'] = $var = 'bar';
$test['bar'] = new ArrayAccessReferenceAssignment($var);

$var = 'foo';
echo $test['bar']; # foo
$alias = &$test['bar'];
$alias = 'hello :)';
echo $var; # hello :)
```

Comment: Thanks @hakre -- I've already got a public facing `bind_data($key, &$variable)` method, I was just trying to alias it. 5.4 would have been a good time to fix this (*among other things*) -- ah well, 6 will be here soon! :P

Comment: There are probably other ways around, like assigning a special object type that represents a reference. I'll try to outline it and add some code.

Comment: Thanks @hakre -- It's tricky, I know; without gratuitous workarounds it may be impossible. Ultimately `$obj[$key] = &$value` needs to invoke `$obj->bind_data($key, $value)` transparently, however given it is impossible it's no major loss. I've learned to accept the limitations of PHP but I can't help question them sometimes.

Comment: I added some other little chunk of code, I don't think it looks that bad, maybe the classname is a bit lengthy ;)

Comment: Thanks @hakre -- That is a solid solution, however it deviates from the simplicity I was hoping to afford by this aliasing. I considered a similar (*essentially identical*) solution previously, but the introduction of an arbitrary object as a stand-in, just to force the reference handling, is something I couldn't see using in production. Inarguably it works, but it's clunky. I updated my question, just to eliminate any ambiguity of what I'm after, but you see where I'm going.

Comment: I know what you're after ;), because I tried something like that to overload the `$GLOBALS` superglobal "array" with `ArrayAccess`, so code using it (e.g. global variables) was proxied automatically. But it's not possible so far. So the code examples are breaking with the very simple array interface we knew since PHP 3 or so. Just added it to show some of the possible work-arounds.

Comment: Well, possible or not (*dammit, it's not*) your persistence has won the accept. Thanks for the workaround suggestions all the same. I've investigated some extensions for PHP, specifically the "operator" extension to support C++ style operator overloading (*I think it had support for many operator variants, such as assignment/assign-by-ref*) but the obvious problem there is of support on client servers. Bah well!  
(*Nevermind, [I don't think it supports it](http://pecl.php.net/package/operator), but it'd be nice all the same*)

Comment: Thanks for linking that extension. I was not aware of it yet.

Comment: No problem -- Unfortunately, it doesn't appear to have seen any action since 2006 (*SVN log shows cosmetic changes 2 years ago*) Why on earth this doesn't get patched into the core is beyond me. The opposition will argue "*operator overloading makes for convolution and ease of abuse!*", but people already write abusive and convoluted PHP.

Answer (score 9):

What the manual is referring to are so called "indirect modifications". Consider the following script:

```
$array = new ArrayObject;
$array['foo'] = array();
$array['foo']['bar'] = 'foobar';
```

In the above script `$array['foo'] = array();` will trigger a `offsetSet('foo', array())`. `$array['foo']['bar'] = 'foobar';` on the other hand will trigger a `offsetGet('foo')`. Why so? The last line will be evaluated roughly like this under the hood:

```
$tmp =& $array['foo'];
$tmp['bar'] = 'foobar';
```

So `$array['foo']` is first fetched by ref and then modified. If your `offsetGet` returns by ref this will succeed. If not you'll get some indirect modification error.

---

What you want on the other hand is the exact opposite: Not fetch a value by reference, but assign it. This would *theoretically* require a signature of `offsetSet($key, &$value)`, but practically this is just **not possible**.

By the way, references are hard to grasp. You'll get lots of non-obvious behavior and this is especially true for array item references (those have some special rules). I'd recommend you to just avoid them altogether.

Comment: Thanks @NikiC -- That feature I was aware of, however it was the last in the list of circumstances, "*...or assigning the array dimension by reference to another variable.*" that got me. In my excitement, I believe I misunderstood; instead trying to do the reverse. As far as actually accomplishing what I'm after, it doesn't appear to be possible, does it?

Comment: Regarding your update -- I'm working on a micro-framework shell, it leverages callbacks and nested "context" objects with cascading data maps, allowing for arbitrary module loading/merging. I've got a pretty good handle on the behaviour of references in this regard, as data needs to be bound (*by reference*) to be passed from scope to scope (*context to context*) however I think I just shat my pants a little when I thought I had read what I read. Though, this would have been a nice syntactic-sugar alias for by `bind_data()` methods. Either way, thanks @NikiC :)