# Reference with PHP SplDoublyLinkedList

Tags: php, arrays, reference, spl

I'm trying to modify the value of my array which is itself in a `linked list`
Sounds like:

```
  $z = new SplDoublyLinkedList();

  $z->push(array('Hello', 0));
  $z->push(array('world', 4));

  $p = & $z->offsetGet(1);                // reference ?

  $p[0]='change';                         // indirection like ? 
  $p[1]=5;


  $q = &$z->offsetGet(1);                 // element of my array remains "world", 4
```

But it doesn't work. 
Of course, If I push `class` object, it works...

Is there a way to have the same behaviour with array() ?
...
Obviously and according to SplDoublyLinkedList declaration, I can't... :(

Comment: You know your code triggers a warning ~ *"PHP Strict Standards:  Only variables should be assigned by reference"*

Comment: Do you also have warning? I have "Strict standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference" for line 8 and 14

Comment: you would have to roll your [own setter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685186/arrayaccess-in-php-assigning-to-offset-by-reference#answer-8685304), because [arrayaccess.offsetset](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) doesn't set by reference.

Answer (score 0):

Use the offsetSet() method

```
  $z = new SplDoublyLinkedList();

  $z->push('Hello');
  $z->push('world');

  $z->offsetSet(0, 'change');
  $z->offsetSet(1, 5);


  $q = $z->offsetGet(1);
```

I don't think this class accepts arrays as the input type for push.